# Adding choices from a file in django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm in with my final project and I need your help!

I need to extract some data from a file and add them as choices in a django form. These are MIDI notes. I need to go through the file that contains the notes (a csv that I have created), extract them and convert them into choices for my form, so I can only choose the ones that exist, because each song has different notes. 
Could someone give me some notions about how to do it?
Any doubt that you have, or if you need more information, do not hesitate to ask!

Edit: I'm adding what I've done yet. In my models.py, I have a created NOTAS_CHOICES, so I want to add this choices to it. With the print I show what NOTAS_CHOICES give, it gives all the values, but they're not showed in the form as they should

```
def Modificacion_Bateria(request, cancion_id):
cancion=Cancion.objects.get(pk=cancion_id)
    cancion.NOTAS_CHOICES=(('0','Nota Pad Verde'),('1','Nota Pad Gris'),('2','Nota Pad Azul'),('3', 'Nota Pad Amarillo'),
    ('4','Nota Pad Rojo'),('35','Acoustic Bass Drum'),('36','Bass Drum 1'),('37','Side Stick'),('38','Acoustic Snare'),('39','Hand Clap'),
    ('40','Electric Snare'),('41','Low Floor Tom'),('42','Closed Hi Hat'),('43','High Floor Tom'),('44','Pedal Hi-Hat'),
    ('45','Low Tom'),('46','Open Hi-Hat'),('47','Low-Mid Tom'),('48','Hi-Mid Tom'),('49','Crash Cymbal 1'),('50','High Tom'),
    ('51','Ride Cymbal 1'),('52','Chinese Cymbal'),('53','Ride Bell'),('54','Tambourine'),('55','Splash Cymbal'),
    ('56','Cowbell'),('57','Crash Cymbal 2'),('58','Vibraslap'),('59','Ride Cymbal 2'),('60','Hi Bongo'),('61','Low Bongo'),
    ('62','Mute Hi Conga'),('63','Open Hi Conga'),('64','Low Conga'),('65','High Timbale'),('66','Low Timbale'),('67','High Agogo'),
    ('68','Low Agogo'),('69','Cabasa'),('70','Maracas'),('71','Short Whistle'),('72','Long Whistle'),('73','Short Guiro'),
    ('74','Long Guiro'),('75','Claves'),('76','Hi Wood Block'),('77','Low Wood Block'),('78','Mute Cuica'),('79','Open Cuica'),
    ('80','Mute Triangle'),('81','Open Triangle'))
    print cancion.NOTAS_CHOICES
if request.method=="POST":
    formulario_modifiacion_bateria=Formulario_Modificacion_Bateria(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=cancion)
    if formulario_modifiacion_bateria.is_valid():
        formulario_modifiacion_bateria.save()
        return redirect('/ListadoCanciones/')
else:
    formulario_modifiacion_bateria=Formulario_Modificacion_Bateria(instance=cancion)
context={'formulario_modifiacion_bateria':formulario_modifiacion_bateria, 'cancion':cancion}
return render(request,"configuracion.html",context)
```

[image]

Comment: You will need to add some code to demonstrate what you have tried and what exactly is not working.

Comment: The way you formulate your 'question', it is absolutely not clear where you are stuck. Do you already have a django project running? Do you have problems with extracting the data from your csv file (that would not be django-related), or with creating that form.. (in any case, first sit down and code sth which you can show us ;)

Comment: I added more info!

Answer (score 0):

I think you approach for adding choices to hard coded choices inside model is not right. I think you can approach like this:

First, declare the Note as a model:

```
class Note(models.Model):
   text = models.TextField()
```

Second, and it as a FK to `Cancion` model:

```
class Cancion(models.Model):
   notes = models.ForeignKey(Note)
   ... # rest of the field
```

Third, I am not sure what is the content of this form `Formulario_Modificacion_Bateria`(please use **Pascal** case when naming the classes), but as it uploads file, I am assuming its the notes file. Assuming the notes file looks like this:

```
...
Nota Pad Verde,
Nota Pad Gris,
...
```

So we can read those files and create entries in Note in view. Like this:

```
def Modificacion_Bateria(request, cancion_id):  # Method should be snake case. Please read PEP-8 Style guide
    ...
    if request.method == "POST":
       ...
       data = csv.DictReader(request.FILES['file'])
       for row in data:
          note, created = Note.objects.get_or_create(text=row[0])
```

Now the choices will be automatically updated in ModelForm relation to `Cancion`. Hope it helps.

Comment: this could be really helpfull. The problem is that each song has his own notes. For example, the song Eye of the Tiger has his own notes, so I need to assign them automatically

Comment: How do you map song to note currently?

Comment: currently I have just one model, called Cancion. notes are choices that are declared inside it. This model has all the atributes, such as song (a midi file) and other some stuff that I need